# Dynamic casting of unknown types for serialization

Tags: c#, .net, serialization, dynamic, casting

I'm writing a custom serializer for struct types for interop with a protocol I can't alter. I'm using reflection to pull out structure member values and write them to a `BinaryWriter`. It's only designed to support basic types and arrays of them.

```
if      (fi.FieldType.Name == "Int16")   bw.Write((Int16)fi.GetValue(obj));
else if (fi.FieldType.Name == "UInt16")  bw.Write((UInt16)fi.GetValue(obj));
else if (fi.FieldType.Name == "Int32")   bw.Write((Int32)fi.GetValue(obj));
else if (fi.FieldType.Name == "UInt32")  bw.Write((UInt32)fi.GetValue(obj));
else if (fi.FieldType.Name == "Int64")   bw.Write((Int64)fi.GetValue(obj));
else if (fi.FieldType.Name == "UInt64")  bw.Write((UInt64)fi.GetValue(obj));
else if (fi.FieldType.Name == "Single")  bw.Write((float)fi.GetValue(obj));
else if (fi.FieldType.Name == "Double")  bw.Write((double)fi.GetValue(obj));
else if (fi.FieldType.Name == "Decimal") bw.Write((decimal)fi.GetValue(obj));
else if (fi.FieldType.Name == "Byte")    bw.Write((byte)fi.GetValue(obj));
else if (fi.FieldType.Name == "SByte")   bw.Write((sbyte)fi.GetValue(obj));
else if (fi.FieldType.Name == "String")  bw.Write((string)fi.GetValue(obj));
```

Obviously this is ugly, and it gets even more ugly when I want to do the same thing with arrays of these types too.

What would be really nice is if I could do something like this:

```
bw.Write( (fi.FieldType) fi.GetValue(obj) );
```

Then do a similar kind of thing for arrays.

Any ideas?

Comment: +1 for this question, I've been looking for a solid way to do this for quite a while.

Comment: If the ugly code ends up being the only option, I generally use T4 templates for this kind of scenario to avoid stupid mistakes and let Visual Studio generate all the code for me automatically.  You would just need a list of types to iterate over or something like that.

Comment: does this help? http://stackoverflow.com/q/907882/103959

Comment: @Jean-BernardPellerin - Nope. It needs to return the actual type, like how a cast does. Otherwise the compiler can't tell which overload of `bw.Write` to use.

Comment: @drdwilcox - `FieldInfo`, which I fetch from `Type.GetFields()`.

Comment: Have you considered using `BinaryFormatter`?  I think that would do your entire requirements in one call.

Comment: @mellamokb - As I stated in my question, I have to serialize to a format that can interop with a protocol that I can't change. Writing static serialization methods for each packet type isn't feasible.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can use reflection to invoke the right version of `Write`

```
public static void WriteField(BinaryWriter bw, object obj, FieldInfo fieldInfo)
{
    typeof(BinaryWriter)
        .GetMethod("Write", new Type[] { fieldInfo.FieldType })
        .Invoke(bw, new object[] { fieldInfo.GetValue(obj) });
}
```

Comment: @Polynomial note that it will be a great deal slower... reflection is notoriously slow. Depending on your scenario it still may be **fast enough**, though.

Comment: Awesome. Works absolutely perfect! :D

Answer (score 2):

This code isn't really ugly at all... it's just repetitive.  But it's actually pretty clean, short and very easy to understand.  If you had a million different types to account for that would be one thing, but there are only a limited number.

If you are able to do what you're wanting to do, it will be hard to maintain if there's ever a problem with it or it needs to do something more and another programmer may not understand it... or you may have forgotten what the heck you did and have to relearn it.

By doing this you will have:
-added additional development time
-reduced readability
-reduced speed
-increased maintenance

Sometimes we like to take problems that are too simple and make them more challenging.  But often good business code is just mundane, boring code.

Comment: With regards to "it's just repetitve", it gets so much more horrible when I've got to account for `T[]`, `List<T>`, `Dictionary<TK,TV>`, as well as the deserialization too.

Comment: I understand.  I think Jacob's answer is a pretty straightforward... I would choose that over vcsJones solution if you want to take this route.

Answer (score 2):

If you want to simplify it, you could use an expression to dynamically make the right call.

```
//Cache the generated method for re-use later, say as a static field of dictionary. It shouldn't grow too-big given the number of overloads of Write.
private static Dictionary<Type, Action<BinaryWriter, object>> _lambdaCache = new Dictionary<Type, Action<BinaryWriter, object>>();

//...

if (!_lambdaCache.ContainsKey(fi.FieldType))
{
    var binaryWriterParameter = Expression.Parameter(typeof(BinaryWriter));
    var valueParameter = Expression.Parameter(typeof(object));
    var call = Expression.Call(binaryWriterParameter, "Write", null, Expression.Convert(valueParameter, fi.FieldType));
    var lambda = Expression.Lambda<Action<BinaryWriter, object>>(call, binaryWriterParameter, valueParameter).Compile();
    _lambdaCache.Add(fi.FieldType, lambda);
}
var write = _lambdaCache[fi.FieldType];
write(bw, fi.GetValue(obj));
```

What we are doing here is dynamically generating the code to make the call that you need to the binary writer. This sounds more complicated than it is, but what we are doing is creating an expression to the "Write" method of a `BinaryWriter`. We also dynamically cast it using `Expression.Convert` so the correct overload of `Write` is called. We take in two parameters of the BinaryWriter and value to write. Finally, we compile the lambda and cache it for that Type for re-use later.

Depending on your needs, this will be a lot faster than using reflection over `BinaryWriter`.

Comment: I will upvote this if you add some more details about how and why this works.

Comment: Will this take the overloads of `Write` into account? It has to call `Write(Int32)` when the returned type of `fi.GetValue(obj)` is `Int32`, despite the fact that the method signature of `GetValue` is `object GetValue(object)`.

Comment: A good solution except it passes the field value as a constant and therefore you would need to create a new lambda and compile it each time you serialize any instance of the class/struct. Could you add an Expression.Convert to convert the field value to the correct type and then make the field value a parameter? Then you could call it repeatedly without having to compile again.

Comment: @PhilWright The field type is already of that type; we don't need to cast it explicitly since the Constant knows what type the Constant is; it just isn't in its strongly typed form. A parameterized version is coming.

Answer (score 2):

I do some very similar code for protobuf-net; `Type.GetTypeCode(...)` is a boon, allowing a `switch`:

```
switch(Type.GetTypeCode(fi.FieldType)) {
    case TypeCode.Int16: bw.Write((Int16)fi.GetValue(obj)); break
    case TypeCode.UInt32: bw.Write((UInt16)fi.GetValue(obj)); break;
        ... etc lots and lots
}
```

still a bit repetitive, but you only look at the `Type` once - the rest is a `switch`.

If you are using 4.0, another trick might be:

```
dynamic value = fi.GetValue(obj);
bw.Write(value);
```

which *will* try to pick the most appropriate overload at runtime. However, **in my view**, this is not reason-enough to use `dynamic` here.

A final thought would be: use meta-programming (such as `ILGenerator`) to create the code at runtime - more complex, but faster, and doesn't have any of these checks at *execution* time (just when preparing the model).

Answer (score 1):

I can think of three options:

1) `BinaryFormatter` - this might be able to accomplish your task very simply, by the `Serialize` method.
2) As you suggest, using reflection.  Code would look something like this:

```
// sample source data
object src = (uint)234;

var bwType = typeof(BinaryWriter);
var argTypes = new Type[] { src.GetType() };
var m = bwType.GetMethod("Write", argTypes);
var args = new object[] { src };
m.Invoke(bw, args);
```

3) Use a T4 template to generate code quickly. The code is still ugly, but at least takes a lot less work to maintain.  I use this pattern often in some of my projects because it's the best of both worlds - no performance penalty from reflection, but all the benefits of dynamically-generated code.

Answer (score 0):

Even if you don't do anything else, `switch` works with strings, and it would make what you have a lot easier to read.

Given the explicit cast is working:

```
Type t = Type.GetType(String.Concat("System.", fi.FieldType.Name));
```

Then use

```
MethodInfo m = typeof(BinaryWriter).GetMethod("Write", new type[] { t });
```

If it's not null

```
m.Invoke(bw, new object[] { fi.GetValue(obj) });
```

This is assuming `FieldType.Name` corresponds to a type that's in scope. Didn't say what would be in there for an array, but if it's `Int16[]`, it's just a bit of jiggery pokery, and may be subclassing `BinaryWriter` and adding some more overloads for types the one in the box doesn't deal with.
If you are doing a lot of this, some sort of cache `Name`, `Type` and `MethodInfo`, would probably be useful.