# Dynamically type a property of a class

Tags: .net, vb.net

```
Module Module1

    Sub Main()
        Dim p As New xyz(MyENUM.C)
    End Sub

End Module

Public Class xyz

    Public Sub New(p As MyENUM)
        Me.pmd = Convert.ChangeType(Me.pmd, GetType(p))
    End Sub

    Public pm As MyENUM
    Public pmd As Object

End Class

Public Enum MyENUM
    A
    B
    C
    D
End Enum
```

I need to set the type of pmd property of my class xyz to the name of the enum myenum. Is there a way to do this?

Think of each Enum property as the name of a class. Based on user input I want just one object of one of those classes. As opposed to creating 4 objects and using just one.

Comment: See here: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/907882/cast-a-property-to-its-actual-type-dynamically-using-reflection

Comment: first, `pm` is not a property, as written it is a Field.  A generic would work better though: `Public Class xyz(Of T)` where you specify the type when you create them

Comment: Why can't you use Generics? You could use type constraints to limit the types that can be used if this is what you want?

Comment: AndAlso: [How do I format my posts using Markdown or HTML?](http://stackoverflow.com/help/formatting).