# Why does the evaluation of Expression.TypeAs return an object of the underlying concrete type and not the interface I've requested it to?

Tags: c#, reflection, expression-trees

The actual answer is in the comments on the answer. I was expecting to get an 'instance' of my interface, which you can't do.

--

> I found a way to do what I actually wanted, which for anyone interested, I've outlined below.

```
public interface Interface<T> { Func<T,T> Property { get; set; } }

public class Concrete : Interface<string>
{
    public Concrete()
    {
        (this as Interface<string>).Property = (s) => { return $"hello, {s}!"; };
    }

    Func<string, string> Interface<string>.Property
    {
        get;
        set;
    }
}

class Program
{
    static void Main(string[] args)
    {
        object obj = new Concrete();

        var propInfo = obj.GetType().GetInterfaces().Single().GetProperty("Property");

        dynamic func = propInfo.GetMethod.Invoke(obj, null);

        var output = func("world");
    }        
}
```

--

I'm doing some codegen and am making heavy use of dynamic types and unfortunately I've hit the dynamic type/explicit interface conundrum.

I can get around this by using `Convert.ChangeType(...)` as outlined [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/909666/6262144) but it requires that `IConvertable` is implemented which will have a large overhead that I don't want to have to do.

I've [found an example](https://stackoverflow.com/a/27584212/6262144) of using Linq expressions to do this using either `Expression.TypeAs` or `Expression.Convert`, however this always returns the underlying concrete type and not the interface I need.

Here's a code example of what I'm trying to do:

```
namespace ExpressionCasting
{
   public interface Interface<T> { void Method(T t); }

   public class ImplementedInterface : Interface<string> 
   { 
      void Interface<string>.Method(string t) { } 
   }

   class Program 
   { 
      static void Main(string[] args)
      {
          var implementedInterface = new ImplementedInterface();      

          // type is an IInterface<string>
          var type = implementedInterface.GetType().GetInterfaces().Single(); 

          // i is always an ImplementedInterface
          var i = Convert(type, implementedInterface); // i is always an ImplementedInterface

          Console.WriteLine(i.GetType()); // i want this to be an IInterface<string> nit and ImplementedInterface. 
      }

      static object Convert(Type type, object subClass)
      {
         var body = Expression.TypeAs(
            Expression.Constant(subClass, subClass.GetType()), type);

         var run = Expression.Lambda(
            body, Expression.Parameter(subClass.GetType())).Compile();

         return run.DynamicInvoke(subClass);
      }
   }
}
```

Any ideas how I can get what I need with expressions or if there is another option I haven't thought of?

Comment: You expectations are not very clear - why getting instance of class implementing the interface is a problem? What else do you expect as result - interfaces don't have instances... Also as Mike [pointed out in answer](http://stackoverflow.com/a/36894929/477420) `i.Method();` will always throw as this method not in interface - make sure your sample actually shows the problem.

Comment: I think you mean `i.Method("foo");` but that doesn't actually change the problem here. Even using `ImpromptuInterface` which is a great Nuget for converting dynamic objects to interfaces you still cannot access explicit implementations like this.

Comment: BTW your Convert method is creating a lambda body that doesn't use a parameter and then calling it with a parameter. Either create a parameter and pass it as the first parameter of TypeAs instead of a constant value, or continue to use Constant and get rid of the lambda parameter and the parameter passed to DynamicInvoke. (Doesn't change problem, just cleans up usage).

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The issue isn't with your expression. It's with the use of dynamic. The DLR isn't looking at explicit interface implementations. It's easy to prove since the following code returns the same exception:

```
dynamic i = new ImplementedInterface();
i.Method(); // throws exception as method is not found.
```

Here is a small article on the issue as well as other surprises when using dynamic: http://csharpindepth.com/Articles/Chapter14/DynamicGotchas.aspx

Comment: Good answer, also if correct it means question has nothing to do with what asked in title and likely to be closed as "typographical error"...

Comment: @mike that's what I meant by this "unfortunately I've hit the dynamic type/explicit interface conundrum."

Comment: You are basically looking to call a private method. IE: Using reflection to the the MethodInfo: GetMethod("Interface<string>.Method", BindingFlags.Instance | BindingFlags.NonPublic). You would need to implement your own DynamicObject to allow this.

Comment: Now the question makes less sense. GetType() on an instance will never return an interface because an interface can never be instantiated.

Comment: The thing to remember is calling an explicit interface is a function of the compiler, not of the runtime.

Comment: @mike - ok, yes. I see where I'm going wrong. This line of thinking was never going to work.

Answer (score 1):

You are returning an object and pushing it into a dynamic parameter.  It is going to go with the simplest possible cast, which is ImplementedInterface, not Interface.  You are effectively undoing the cast done in your Convert method by down casting to type object and then invoking as a dynamic variable.

Answer (score 0):

Your expression looks good.
But there is an issue with `dynamic` itself.

Even it this case (see below) you will have an error:

```
public interface Interface<T> { void Method(T t); }

public class ImplementedInterface : Interface<string> { void Interface<string>.Method(string t) { } }

void Main()
{
    dynamic i = (Interface<string>)new ImplementedInterface();

    i.Method(); // throws exception as method is not found.
}
```