# Cast a property to its actual type dynamically using reflection (where actual type is generic) v2

Tags: c#, generics, casting, propertyinfo

This is a slightly modified version of the question I asked before [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/64485988/cast-a-property-to-its-actual-type-dynamically-using-reflection-where-actual-ty).

The actual position is like below:

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using System.Reflection;
using System.Text;
using System.Threading.Tasks;

namespace cns01
{
    class Program
    {
        public class DataFieldInfo2<T>
        {
            public bool IsSearchValue { get; set; } = false;
            public T Value { get; set; }
        }

        public class SmartRowVertrag
        {
            public DataFieldInfo2<int> ID { get; set; }
            public DataFieldInfo2<string> VSNR { get; set; }
        }

        static void Main(string[] args)
        {
            SmartRowVertrag tester = new SmartRowVertrag();
            tester.ID = new DataFieldInfo2<int>() { Value = 777, IsSearchValue = false };
            tester.VSNR = new DataFieldInfo2<string>() { Value = "234234234", IsSearchValue = true };

            var g = RetData3(tester);
        }

        public static object RetData3(object fsr)
        {
            object retVal = new object();
            var props = fsr.GetType().GetProperties();
            foreach (var prop in props)
            {
                PropertyInfo propInfo = prop.GetType().GetProperty("IsSearchValue"); // <-- here I get null
                propInfo = prop.PropertyType.GetProperty("IsSearchValue"); // here I get a propertyInfo, but...
                dynamic property = propInfo.GetValue(fsr, null); // ...<-- here fires error
                var result = property.IsSearchValue;
                if (result == true)
                {
                    // doThis
                }
            }
            return retVal;
        }
    }
}
```

I do need to get the boolean value stored in `IsSearchValue` to to accomplish things.

Thanks beforehand.

I mostly appreciate any helping answer.

Comment: "here fires error" doesn't tell use very much. Please specify the error, with a stack trace, in the post. (It's nice to have a complete example though - thanks for that.)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`fsr` is the `SmartRowVertrag`. You're trying to get the `IsSearchValue` from that - but it doesn't exist.

Instead, you'll need to call `GetValue` twice - once on `prop`, passing in `fsr` (so which is equivalent to using `fsr.ID` or `dsr.VSNR`) and then once on `propInfo` passing in the result of that first call.

Next, your `dynamic` use is trying to get `IsSearchValue` on the result of `propInfo.GetValue()` - you're trying to evaluate `something.IsSearchValue.IsSearchValue`, effectively.

Here's corrected code for that part:

```cs
public static object RetData3(object fsr)
{
    object retVal = new object();
    var props = fsr.GetType().GetProperties();
    foreach (var prop in props)
    {
        PropertyInfo propInfo = prop.PropertyType.GetProperty("IsSearchValue");
        if (propInfo != null)
        {
            object fieldInfo = prop.GetValue(fsr);
            object isSearchValue = propInfo.GetValue(fieldInfo);
            if (isSearchValue.Equals(true))
            {
                Console.WriteLine($"{prop.Name} has a searchable field");
            }
        }
    }
    return retVal;
}
```

You could avoid using reflection twice though if you had either a non-generic interface that `DataFieldInfo2<T>` implemented, or a base class. For example:

```cs
public interface IDataFieldInfo
{
    bool IsSearchValue { get; }
}

public class DataFieldInfo2<T> : IDataFieldInfo
{
    ...
}
```

You could then make your reflection code much clearer:

```cs
public static object RetData3(object fsr)
{
    var fieldProperties = fsr.GetType().GetProperties()
        .Where(prop => typeof(IDataFieldInfo).IsAssignableFrom(prop.PropertyType));
    foreach (var fieldProperty in fieldProperties)
    {
        var field = (IDataFieldInfo) fieldProperty.GetValue(fsr);
        if (field.IsSearchValue)
        {
            Console.WriteLine($"{fieldProperty.Name} is a search value field");
        }
    }
    
    // We don't actually know what you're trying to return
    return null;
}
```